# CSS nested dropdown-menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Have a look at my page at http://81.216.141.82/flygklubb
Hover the first menu item "Flygplan" and then hover the first child item. As you can see the child to "DELTA 3000 MK2" appears on top of that item, but i want that level to appear right to the first level, but i don't want to have any fixed values for position. How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Something alongst the lines of:

```
#topnavigation ul li ul li ul{
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 140px;
}
```

Should do it. It's not necessarily fixed positions, more relative positions to the original element.

Comment: That works for the first item, but thing is then the margin-left is fixed, and some drop-down child items are wider than 140px, and then that doesn't look very good :/

Comment: You could use JS to reposition each item, when you show it. So on your rollover at something along the lines of $(this).css('margin-left',$(this).parent().left). Not sure of exact syntax but you get the idea

Comment: I get what you mean, but think that the ideal solution would be to use css only...